# ObjectIDs in other collections without getting duplicate key error

Tags: javascript, mongodb, mongoose, nosql

I am getting the following error when trying to create a document in a collection.

`MongoServerError: E11000 duplicate key error collection: stock-trading-system-db.trades index: user_id_1 dup key: { user_id: ObjectId('6266de71b90b594dab9037f3') }`

Here is my schema:

```js
const tradeSchema = new mongoose.Schema({
    user_id: {
        type: Schema.Types.ObjectId,
        ref: 'User',
        required: true
    },
    stock_id: {
        type: Schema.Types.ObjectId,
        ref: 'Stock',
        required: true
    },
    stock_amount: {
        type: Number,
        required: true
    },
    stock_value: {
        type: Number,
        required: true
    },
    time_of_trade: {
        type: Date,
        required: true,
        default: new Date()
    },
    trade_status: {
        type: String,
        enum: ['Approved', 'Declined', 'Pending'],
        required: true,
        default: 'Pending'
    }
}, { collection: 'trades' })
```

I don't want user_id and stock_id to be unique, i just want it to check that those ObjectIDs exist in their respective collections before making the trade document. How do i achieve this?

Answer (score 0):

It looks like a collection saves the schema that is defined in mongoose, and even if you change the schema, the unique values will stay the same inside the collection.

So even though i had removed

```
unique: true;
```

from my mongoose schema, it hadn't removed this from the collection in my DB.

Therefore the solution to this is to delete the collection and recreate it.

Comment: before dropping the collection you should identify what indexes exist. (Mongoshell command `db.trades.getIndexes();`).  Perhaps Mongoose is creating an index on your behalf and when you drop the collection you also clear out the index, thus no dup key exception on the insert after drop.